# AngularJS: Aligning elements from different ng-repeats

Tags: angularjs

**EDIT:**

Created a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/dbGI65ZTGjt9ZN1KTm6A?p=preview).

I have a JSON string with 2 child objects.

```
{
   "ParentA":
   { 
      ...
   },
   "ParentB":
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

Both of these objects have children, and some of the children in ParentA have the same name as some of the children in ParentB.  I want to align the objects with the same name side-by-side in my HTML, like this:

```
ParentA.Child1    ParentB.Child1
ParentA.Child2
ParentA.Child3    ParentB.Child3
```

If there are children with the same name, then align them side-by-side on the same line.  If there isn't a child with the same name as a child from ParentA, then just display the ParentA child with a blank space where the ParentB child usually would be.

ParentB is a subset of ParentA, so there will never be a child of ParentB that isn't a child of ParentA.

I am currently using nested `ng-repeats` along with an `ng-if` to achieve what I want, but it's slowing down the page's loading time; for every child of ParentA, it loops through every child of ParentB until it finds a match.

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl as appCtrl" flex="">
    <div ng-controller="ClusterCtrl as modelCtrl">
        <md-grid-list md-cols-sm="1" md-cols-md="2" md-cols-gt-md="6"
                      md-row-height-gt-md="1:1" md-row-height="4:3" md-gutter="8px"
                      md-gutter-gt-sm="4px" class="gridList" ng-repeat="clusterA in instances.ParentA.CLUSTERS">
            <md-grid-tile md-rowspan="1" md-colspan="3" md-colspan-sm="1" class="gridTile">
                <md-grid-tile-footer style="text-align:center;"><h3>{{clusterA.name}}</h3></md-grid-tile-footer>
            </md-grid-tile>

            <md-grid-tile ng-repeat="clusterB in instances.ParentB.CLUSTERS"
                          ng-if="clusterA.name == clusterB.name"
                          md-rowspan="1" md-colspan="3" md-colspan-sm="1" class="gridTile">
                <md-grid-tile-footer style="text-align:center;"><h3>{{clusterB.name}}</h3></md-grid-tile-footer>
            </md-grid-tile>
        </md-grid-list>
    </div>
</div>
```

I was thinking about taking care of this logic in the controller, but don't know how to implement it.

**UPDATE:**

I don't think I can call this progress, but I'll post it up anyway.  Loading the DOM takes 60ms longer than it did before, which isn't good; that is because I have 3 loops in the controller, one of which is nested.  Yet, the control flow logic has been abstracted from the view and placed into a controller.

```
.controller('FlexClusterCtrl', ['$scope', 'ModelSvc', function($scope, ModelSvc) {
    $scope.init = function() {
        ModelSvc.getInstances().success(function(data) {
            $scope.paNames = [];
            $scope.pbNames = [];
            $scope.joinedNames = new Array();
            $scope.instances = data;
            $scope.pa = data.pa;
            $scope.pb = $scope.instances.pb;

            angular.forEach($scope.pb.clusters, function(pbItem) {
                $scope.paNames.push(pbItem.name);
            });

            console.log($scope.paNames);

            angular.forEach($scope.wng.clusters, function(paItem) {
                $scope.pbNames.push(paItem.name);
            });

            angular.forEach($scope.pbNames, function(paName) {
                angular.forEach($scope.paNames, function(pbName) {
                    if(paName === pbName) {
                        var temp = paName;
                        $scope.joinedNames.push(temp);
                        $scope.joinedNames.push(temp);
                    }
                });
                if($scope.joinedNames.indexOf(paName) < 0) {
                    $scope.joinedNames.push(paName);
                    $scope.joinedNames.push(null);
                }
            });

            console.log($scope.joinedNames);
        });
    };

    $scope.init();
}]);
```

And the condensed HTML, without the nested content.

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl as appCtrl" flex="">
    <div ng-controller="ClusterCtrl as modelCtrl">
        <md-grid-list md-cols-sm="1" md-cols-md="2" md-cols-gt-md="2"
            md-row-height-gt-md="3:1" md-row-height="4:3" md-gutter="8px"
            md-gutter-gt-sm="4px" class="gridList" >
            <md-grid-tile ng-repeat="cluster in joinedNames track by $index"
                md-rowspan="1" md-colspan="1" md-colspan-sm="1" class="gridTile">
                <md-grid-tile-footer style="text-align:center;"><h3>{{cluster}}</h3></md-grid-tile-footer>
            </md-grid-tile>
        </md-grid-list>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice how there is only one `ng-repeat` and no `ng-if`.  That is what I wanted, but I thought it would speed up page loading time, which isn't the case according to Chrome's dev tools.  I'll be working towards a better solution.  This solution basically just created a new data structure in the controller.  It was mainly for testing purposes to see if I could actually abstract the control logic from the view; now it's time to do that more efficiently.

Comment: alternative would be to map a whole new array before sending to view. Create a demo with sample data

Comment: Working on writing a program to reformat my JSON string so that I can actually use it on SO in the future without giving away sensitive data.  I'll post up back in here when that's complete.

Comment: numerous dummy json generators you can use

Answer (score 0):

I would think adding a controller method that just returns the children you need and calling it from your ng-repeat, so you can eliminate the ng-if would do the trick.

```
clusterB in instances.parent2.getKids(...)
```

Not sure I follow the data model well enough, maybe this isn't possible.

Comment: Yes, I'm working on abstracting the control logic from the view into a controller.  I still haven't figured out how I'm going to get everything I want from one ng-repeat.  If a child from parentA has the same name as a child from parentB, I want those children to be displayed side-by-side.  When that's not the case (i.e. when there is a unique child in parentA or parentB), I want there to be a blank space where the matching child usually would be.  I updated the plnkr to visually show want I want.  I want to keep the visuals the same, but abstract the control logic from the view into a ctrl.

Comment: That is an interesting challenge. Please post your solution after you nail it!